# about playing songs by Cocoalibspotify, does app download the cache of songs like mp3, DRM format that I can do some remix of it?

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

about playing songs by Cocoalibspotify, does app download the cache of songs like mp3, DRM format that I can do some remix of it ?

If the answer is NO, what kind of streaming format send while playing Spotify's song from Cocoalibspotify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaLibSpotify passes audio to your application as raw PCM data. However, the standard Terms of Use for the library forbid this sort of remixing.

All of this information and more is available in CocoaLibSpotify's documentation.

Comment: Thank you for instant reply, @iKenndac

But Can I analyze the raw PCM data to get speed, genre, instrument of the song that I can show real-time interactive message wit users ?

as for forbid this sort of remix, why does pacemaker can do that?

I'm sorry CocoaLibSpotify's documentation is so huge, I tried to find out for a week, then I can't figure out where it shows the definition and explanation of raw PCM data process, can you help to point out that ?

Comment: The standard Terms of Use forbid it. I guess Pacemaker negotiated a special contract or something. Look for the `SPSessionAudioDeliveryDelegate` documentation for info on how audio is delivered, and the `SPCoreAudioController` class for an example implementation.

Comment: appreciate you deeply.

Comment: My thought in the beginning is introduce people music by speed, gnere, instrument. But now, if analyzing raw PCM data is forbidden, I have to figure out another way to let people discover music.
might be social, might be station held by editor, might any stuff else I never come up with.
http://playlists.net/ and http://tunigo.com/ did a great job on that.

Comment: Analysing is not forbidden - modifying is.